# SQL code to create attached output from attached inputs

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to write a SQL Query in DB2 to create Output (link below) by joining Table1 (link below) and Table2 (link below).

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGoTl.png)

[Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrE1S.png)

[Table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9QCq.png)

Comment: Please show your code and indicate where you are having trouble.  Thanks.

Comment: It's better to post data as text rather than a link to an image

Comment: Also, I downvoted because this is a zero effort question. There is no query attempt or even a description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

here is a terrible answer for you:

select * from (select *, case when not exists (select state from table2 where table2.state = table1.state) then 'state not listed' when exists (select state from table2 where table2.state = table1.state) then 'state match' concat case when not exists (select city from table2 where table2.state = table1.state and table2.city = table1.city) then ', city not listed'  when exists (select visited from table2 where table2.state=table1.state and table2.city=table1.city and table2.visited = 'N') then ', city match, not visited' end  end as status from  table1) where status is not null